# Alternative to CSS3 <hr> tag of simple styles with fade out edges if this do not work and a child standard <hr> tag kick in instead?

Tags: css

Alternative to CSS3 < hr > tag of simple styles with fade out edges if this do not work and a child statement or else statement for standard < hr > tag underneath the hr style as code below.

There is CSS3 < hr > tag of simple styles with fade out edges see a link 
http://css-tricks.com/simple-styles-for-horizontal-rules.

Is there a fallback if this < hr > simple styles with fade out edges do not work and a standard < hr > kink in instead? I'm using jQuery1.6.4 Please advise?

```
 hr { border: 0; height: 1px; 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));       
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
 width:100%; 
 }

 .hr { border: 0; height: 1px; 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));       
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are better off using hr that way if you are worried about a fall back, but you can probably replace the hr with a div with an image inside or as a background if the browser doesn't support css gradients, to be able to detect such feature you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

once you have modernizr on your html you can test with jQuery if css gradients are available to your client, [I normally do it like this](http://jsfiddle.net/mrpollo/HRba8/6/), but there might be a better way of doing this using Modernizr js API.

Please let me know if it works for you, and good luck!

HTML

```
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
```

CSS

```
hr {
    border: 0; height: 1px; 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));       
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    width:100%; 
}

.hr {
    border: 0; height: 1px; 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));       
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

.no-js .glossy,
.no-cssgradients .glossy {
    background: url("images/glossybutton.png");
}

.cssgradients .glossy {
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #555, #333);
}
​
```

JS

```
(function($){
if( $('.cssgradients').length == 0 ){
    // no css gradients
    $('hr').each(function(index){
        // replace for image maybe?
    });
}
}(jQuery);
```

​

​

Comment: Thank you r roche and that is brillant. I accept this as a solution.

Comment: @rroche. You have a small typo in your jsfiddle that will keep it from working correctly. No biggie... You just mis-spelled the '.length' method as '.lenght'. Corrected jsfiddle example is now at http://jsfiddle.net/HRba8/5/.

Comment: thanks @Epiphany I updated the link and added code to the answer.